# Keras: how to get top-k accuracy

Tags: python, keras

I would like to get the top-k accuracy for my model in keras.

I have found a post here:[How to calculate top5 accuracy in keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42327006/how-to-calculate-top5-accuracy-in-keras) suggesting the following:

```
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

top_values, top_indices = K.get_session().run(tf.nn.top_k(_pred_test, k=5))
```

The output just gives me two arrays:

top_values:

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

top_indices:

```
array([[12,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [13,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [15,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       ...,
       [12,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [17,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [18,  0,  1,  2,  3]])
```

How would I calculate the actual score from these values?

Comment: if you use a keras model: How about passing the top_k_accuracy metric to your model during compilation?

Comment: would I have to retrain the entire model or can I access the metric after I compile the model? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: Well the metric is just a function which has the arguments predictions and labels. So just do your predictions on your test dataset and feed it with the labels to the function and you get your result. Since keras recognize the input as numpy arrays it will directly compute the result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok here is the code that works for me, in case someone else stumbles upon similar issues - the missing link for me was using ".evaluate":

```
import functools
top3_acc = functools.partial(keras.metrics.top_k_categorical_accuracy, k=3)

top3_acc.__name__ = 'top3_acc'

model.compile(Adam(lr=.001),#
    optimizers.RMSprop(lr=2e-5),
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        metrics=['accuracy','top_k_categorical_accuracy',top3_acc])

    model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
```

where 'top_k_categorical_accuracy' gives me the score for k=5 (standard) and top3_acc can be adjusted by changing k=3 in the function call.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a valid line of code anymore. This always return 1 in my code. The following line of code works for me. I have keras 2.7.0 and also tensorflow 2.7.0.
`metrics=['accuracy', SparseTopKCategoricalAccuracy(k=2)]`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively,

```
from keras.metrics import top_k_categorical_accuracy

def topKacc(Y_true, Y_pred):
  return top_k_categorical_accuracy(Y_true, 
                                    Y_pred, 
                                    k = int_here)
metrics = [topKacc, ...]

model.compile(...,
              metrics=metrics)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another simple way of doing it.

```
def top_3_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k=3)

model.compile(..........., metrics=[top_3_accuracy])
```