# Keras top k accuracy after training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to get the top k accuracy of a model after it is trained. I don't want to explicitly optimize for achieving a high top k accuracy, but rather, just figure out what the top k accuracy is after the model has been trained.

All the examples I've seen thus far require top_k to be supplied as a metric during compilation.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42327006/how-to-calculate-top5-accuracy-in-keras) out. Let the community know if your problem is different.

Comment: @MaharshiRoy I saw that post. That method (presumably) works should I train with top_k_accuracy as a metric, but when I try to do so afterwards, it doesn't work.