# How to get top K predictions using Keras

Tags: python, keras, prediction

I finished training a model with Keras, but I have a problem that I can't get the top K results. I know there is a function called `tf.nn.top_k` in tensorflow, but how can I use it in Keras?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate top5 accuracy in keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42327006/how-to-calculate-top5-accuracy-in-keras)

Comment: It would be useful if the question specified whether you want to calculate the topN for the purposes of loss calculation, a metric or simply to interpret inference. Those are different scenarios.

Comment: store the all the prediction in a list and and apply sorted(list_name,reverse = True) and print the first 5 prediction of list

Answer (score 2):

You can try with the below code.

```
y_preds = self.model.predict(x)
y_preds = np.argsort(y_preds, axis=1)[:,-n:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Look, I use tf.nn.top_k in a model to code the beam search algorithm to predict the next word. It's not part of the model since it's a strategy to decode the results of the model.
But the for the beam search, the use of tf.nn.top_k it's just a tinny line code like that

```
topk_values, topk_ids = tf.nn.top_k(predictions, k=beam_size)
```

It gives you the top k values of the predictions and the indices where the values are stored.
However, as recommends Joy, numpy is ok and I think it's the usual choice when we use keras. For example, for a text classification we can use the probabilities to see how confident is the prediction or to classify an item in more than one category.

```
predictions = model.predict(X)
rates = np.fliplr( np.sort(predictions, axis=1)[:,-k:] )
categories = np.fliplr( np.argsort(predictions, axis=1)[:,-k:] )
```

Note that I use numpy fliplr just to reorder in descendent the sorted results

Good luck!